# iOS: Keyboard replacement

Tags: keyboard, ios

Is there any way to replace the keyboard as you can do with the Android? If not completely replace, is there a way to extend it and add additional functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the keyboard view by adding a custom inputAccessoryView as a property to your textField or textView, or you can replace the keyboard by adding a custom inputView.